# ClearAll["Global`*"] stops working with Context set to 'unique to this Notebook'

Tags: notebooks, kernel, clear

I just changed my default notebook context to 'unique to this Notebook' so that variables don't roll across numerous open notebooks.  Doing this, however, made the command ClearAll["Global*"] stop working to clear all declared variables.  I also tried, `ClearAll[Evaluate[Context[] <> "*"]]`, but that didn't work either.  Any ideas?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

As soon as you set your notebook context to 'unique to this Notebook', the notebook's context is no longer `` Global` ``, but, well, unique to the notebook.

I can't test right now, but assuming you are not in an explicitly opened context (like after `Begin` or `BeginPackage`), I think the following should work:

```
ClearAll@@{$Context<>"*"}
```

At least it works in a kernel with manually changed `$Context`.

Comment: It works, so +1.

Comment: Awesome, totally works!  Any ideas why variables aren't going back to blue (from black)?

Comment: @zhermes: I have no idea. IIRC the variables actually already start out being black when the notebook uses its own context (can't check now); no idea why. Maybe the colouring algorithm doesn't take the different context into account correctly.

Comment: I think you could just do ``ClearAll@"`*"``...

Answer (score 3):

I think instead of `` ClearAll["Global`*"] ``, you can just `` Clear["`*"] ``. This should work.