# Area of volume of revolution

Tags: homework

I want to calculate the *exact area* of this volume:

```
RevolutionPlot3D[
 f[x_] = Sqrt[28 x]
 , {x, 0, 21}
 , Axes -> True
 ]
```

Additionally, I wish to see $x$ and $y$ axis.

Before you vote down my question because I don't know how mathematica works and dare asking, I did try to solve it in the documentation. But [that page](https://www.wolfram.com/mathematica/new-in-10/basic-and-formula-regions/region-measures-length-area-volume-etc.html) does not reply to my question.

```
Area[f[x]]
```

gives output

> Area::reg: 20.105968871208372` is not a correctly specified region.
>   Area[20.106]

Comment: Thanks for accepting my answer, but I think you were too hasty doing that. While *accepting* is one of the [things to do after your question is answered](https://wolfr.am/v57DB3p4), we recommend that all users should **test answers before [voting](https://wolfr.am/v57ItzJq)** and **wait 24 hours before [accepting](https://wolfr.am/v57LwTXD)** the best one. That allows people in all timezones to answer your question and an opportunity for other users to point alternatives, caveats or limitations of the available answers.

Comment: Ok, I understand. Do you wish me to unaccept it?

Comment: It's up to you, you could un-check now and come back tomorrow and accept the best answer then, or you could just take the idea and apply it in the future.

Comment: I take the idea then. Your code works beautifully so seems unfair to uncheck.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It seems that `f[x]` is evaluating to a number. Probably you [`Set`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Set.html) an [`OwnValues`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/OwnValues.html) for `x`? Check by evaluating `?x`.

[`Area`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Area.html) is only defined for regions, parametric surfaces and sets of coordinates, not single numbers nor plots.

Therefore, my the strategy is to first, start with a [fresh kernel](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/175670/10397). Then, create a Cartesian parametric expression for the surface and use `Area` on that.

To create the parametric expression in Cartesian coordinates the easiest way is to start with the cylindrical coordinantes  `{r, θ, f[r]}` and then use [`CoordinateTransform`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/CoordinateTransform.html)

```
CoordinateTransform[
 "Cylindrical" -> "Cartesian"
 , {r, θ, Sqrt[28 r]}
]
```

See also this [other answer](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/176131/10397) using [`ParametricRegion`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/ParametricRegion.html).

Here my take on it.

```
With[
 {
  parmcartsn = CoordinateTransform[
    "Cylindrical" -> "Cartesian"
    , {r, θ, Sqrt[28 r]}
    ]
  },
 Column[
  {
   ParametricPlot3D[
    parmcartsn
    , {r, 0, 21}
    , {θ, 0, 2 π}
    , PlotLabel -> TraditionalForm[parmcartsn]
    ],
   Area[
    parmcartsn
    , {r, 0, 21}
    , {θ, 0, 2 π}
    ]
   }
  ]
 ]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Comment: Thank you. I would have never come to that answer. I don't know how to parametrize with cos and sin, how can I do it with an easy f(x) function?

Comment: @Dovendyr see my edit.

Comment: Let me try that thing ''cartesian to parametric'' with another math problem. I'll post a new question if I'm lost...

Answer (score 10):

```
r = ParametricRegion[{r Cos[ϕ], Sin[ϕ] r, 
    Sqrt[28 r]}, {{r, 0, 21}, {ϕ, 0, 2 π}}]
```

[image]

```
Area[r]
```

49/2 π (14 Sqrt[3] - ArcSinh[Sqrt[3]])

Comment: Thank you, Rom38! That was also short and neat.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe I'm missing something but shouldn't $ f(x) = \sqrt{28 x} $ yield a concave function as opposed to the convex examples shown in the anwers above?
My approach would be to use the formula for [Solids of Revolution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Solid_of_revolution)
:
    $$
V=\pi \cdot \int_{a}^{b}f(x)^{2}dx
$$
analogous to $V = \pi r^2\cdot h$ for a cylindrical body where $r$ is the radius and $h$ is the cylinder height.
This, evaluated by Mathematica or otherwise (I did it quick'n dirty by hand, so I hope I didn't make an error) should give:
    $$
\pi \cdot 12348 \approx 38792.39
$$

After misunderstanding the question at first, mistakenly stopping at giving the Volume of the Solid of revolution, the addendum for the surface area follows here:
Further reading in the wikipedia article linked above also gives a pretty simple equation for the surface area **with respect to rotation around the x-axis:**
    $$
S = 2 \pi \int_{a}^{b} f(x) dx
$$
in analogy to $S = 2\pi r \cdot h$ for a cylindrical body.
Because an exact result is required, I'll stop short of giving an value, as square roots are involved. But it should be easy enough from here.

Comment: The exercise is to calculate an area so I don't know if it applies....

Comment: yeah, 'area of volume' in the OP sounds a bit confusing. I think the above approaches somehow include an axis swap from x to y. This may be perfectly reasonable, though I..don't really get it.

Comment: Your formula gives a volume; the question is the area of the volume, like its skin (?). Don't know what the correct English expression would be.

Comment: oh, the surface area? Yeah,  in that case,  my solution won't help 

Comment: thanks for trying to help in any case!

Comment: thought a bit about that further; the Area should also be calculat-able with pretty elementary means. Will probably update my answer for that.

Comment: voted you up :)!