# Drawing function that rotates around y-axis with coordinate transform

Tags: plotting, homework

At last I solved [a math problem](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2832257/volume-of-revolution-around-y-axis) and trying to illustrate it in Mathematica TO NOT FORGET.

I used that code. I works and I get a cake-form. But I think it's missing a big $x$ and a big $y$ axis in the middle.

```
RevolutionPlot3D[{{x, (4 x - x^2)}}, {x, 0, 4}, {th, 0, 2 π},  
Boxed -> False, BoxRatios -> {1, 1, 0.3}, ViewPoint -> {0, 4, 0},  
AxesLabel -> {x, y, z}]
```

A nice person @rhermans helped me [to draw another problem here](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/176129/area-of-volume-of-revolution).

So I tried to apply his code (to apply and learn) but it's not working.

```
CoordinateTransform[  "Cylindrical" -> "Cartesian", {r, θ, 4 x - x^2}]

With[{parmcartsn = CoordinateTransform["Cylindrical" -> "Cartesian", {r, θ, 4 x - x^2}]},
 Column[{ParametricPlot3D[parmcartsn, {r, 0, 4}, {θ, 0, 2 π}, 
PlotLabel -> TraditionalForm[parmcartsn]], Area[parmcartsn, {r, 0, 4}, {θ, 0, 2 π}]}]]
```

I just get a sad empty box with coordinates...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Changing `4 x - x^2` to `4 r - r^2` gives the desired result:

```
With[{parmcartsn = CoordinateTransform["Cylindrical" -> "Cartesian", {r, θ, 4 r - r^2}]},
 Column[{ParametricPlot3D[parmcartsn, {r, 0, 4}, {θ, 0, 2 π}, 
    PlotLabel -> TraditionalForm[parmcartsn]], 
  Area[parmcartsn, {r, 0, 4}, {θ, 0, 2 π}]}]]
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you, it does indeed.