# Mathematica is picking up variable definition from other files

Tags: variable-definitions, variable

Mathematica is using definitions from other open files in the same folder.

I want variables not defined in a particular file to be treated as undefined variables. I do not want Mathematica to pick the expression of these variables from other files. Is there any way to go about this?

Comment: Maybe run `Exit[]` in your current notebook before you execute anything else in it? That should unload all the definitions.

Comment: @Shredderroy That works. Thanks!

Comment: Have a look to [this question](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/175670/10397), you can also set a context  ["unique to this Notebook"](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4897013/3054385)

Comment: @rhermans Thanks for the second link. Changing the global policy for CellContext to "Notebook" does exactly what I was looking for.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Set the option value for [`CellContext`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/CellContext.html) to `Notebook`:

```
SetOptions[EvaluationNotebook[], CellContext -> Notebook]
```

Use `$FrontEndSession` (respectively, `$FrontEnd`) in place of `EvaluationNotebook[]` for the option setting to apply to all the notebooks in the current session (respectively, to all notebooks globally).

[image]

Comment: This works, but changing the default global policy for CellContext was more convenient for me. [Link for future reference](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4896011/mathematica-separating-notebooks/4897013#4897013)