# How do I find the zero of this function?

Tags: equation-solving

How do I find the zero of this function:

```
Ef=5.53;
e=1.6*10^-19;
qc[w1_?NumericQ] := 
  w1 (1/(2 a[w1]) (1 + Sqrt[1 - 4/(27 a[w1])])^(1/3) + 
     1/(2 a[w1]) (1 - Sqrt[1 - 4/(27 a[w1])])^(1/3));

a[w1_?NumericQ] := 
  Piecewise[{{2/3, 
     w1 < 0.62}, {0.9069 + 0.3577 w1^(-2/3) - 1.0565 w1^(-1) + 
      1.478 w1^(-4/3) - 0.4524 w1^(-5/3), w1 > 0.62}}];
wmax2[w1_?NumericQ, T_?NumericQ] := Min[T - Ef, T/2];
s4[w1_?NumericQ, T_?NumericQ] := (Pi e^4)/
   T (Log[wmax2[w1, T]/qc[w1]] + T/(T - wmax2[w1, T]) - T/(
     T - qc[w1]) + 2 Log[(T - wmax2[w1, T])/(T - qc[w1])]);
```

If I plot it it crosses the x axis, so there is a zero, but `NSolve[s4[100,T]==0,T]` gives a complex number as a solution and says to use `Refine`, and `Refine` can't find the zero.

Comment: `FindRoot` perhaps? You haven't defined `qc` for us, so we can't investigate more.

Comment: Use `FindRoot`. Can't say more, because you didn't give full definitions of your symbols (e.g. wmax2, qc). You have asked 48 questions on this site so far, you should know how to ask a good question by now.

Comment: @MarcoB added the rest of the function I am sorry.

Comment: @mattiav27 `a` is still undefined. The best way to check for these things is to copy back your posted code in a clean MMA session ([see this Q](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/175670/27951)) and try to execute it. It has to work under those conditions, because that's what we will be trying on our own computers.

Comment: @MarcoB Added the definition of `a`

Comment: @mattiav27 Thank you. I reverted my downvote. See my answer below.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With the full code, we can explore the plot to find an initial estimate of the root. COnsidering the extremely small values of the function, I used a `LogPlot` on its absolute value:

```
LogPlot[Abs@s4[100, T], {T, 100, 250}, PlotRange -> All]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

We confirm that with a regular plot:

```
Plot[s4[100, T], {T, 120, 250}, PlotRange -> All]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

A good estimate for the root appears to be around $180$. We can feed that into `FindRoot` as a starting point for root search:

```
FindRoot[s4[100, T], {T, 180}]
(* Out: {T -> 183.495} *)
```

Answer (score 0):

With a large value for `PlotPoints` we can also use purely graphical approach to get the roots:

```
Normal[Plot[s4[100, T], {T, 120, 250}, PlotRange -> All, 
   MeshFunctions -> {#2 &}, Mesh -> {{0}}, 
   MeshStyle -> PointSize[Large], PlotPoints -> 300]] /. 
 Point[x_] :> {Point[x], Text[Framed @ Style[x, 14], Offset[{50,-30}, x]]}
```

[image]

Use

```
Text[Framed@Style[root = T/. FindRoot[s4[100, T], {T, x[[1]]}, WorkingPrecision->20 ], 12]
```

in place of `Text[...]` above to get

[image]