# Mathematica's output changes when I change order of series

Tags: series-expansion

The output of below codes are different when I run them. Does any one knows what could be the reason? They should be the same, because it shouldn't depend on order of expansion. Could anyone discover the source of difference? Any answers is highly appreciated.

```
f2x = Import["https://pastebin.com/RAPC8KpX"];

   F1=  Series[
        Series[f2x, {r12, Infinity,2}] // Normal, {z, Infinity, 1}] // Normal;


   F2=  Series[
        Series[f2x, {z, Infinity,1}] // Normal, {r12, Infinity, 2}] // Normal;
```

Comment: So what is f2x?  Clearly we cannot answer this question without this basic information.

Comment: @HolgerMate:  Please give us a representative function for f2x.  Again, we can't help at all without some function here.

Comment: I also cannot reproduce the problem, neither in version 11.0.1 nor in version 11.3 for macOS.

Comment: No, you should hope somebody else does with this non-explanation. I'm not going to try any more. You make it impossible for me to help you.

Comment: @HolgerMate Also please delete the comments that have become obsolete. This question will be here forever, try to make it readable for future visitors.

Answer (score 4):

I get the same result in any case (Mathematica 11.3 Win 7 64). I think you may have a lingering definition, try starting with a [clean kernel](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/175670/10397).

```
f2x = Import["https://pastebin.com/raw/Q6pW366F"];

ser1 = Series[Series[f2x, {r12, Infinity, 2}] // Normal, {z, Infinity, 1}] // Normal;

ser2 = Series[Series[f2x, {z, Infinity, 1}] // Normal, {r12, Infinity, 2}] // Normal;

ser3 = Normal@Series[f2x, {z, Infinity, 1}, {r12, Infinity, 2}];

FullSimplify[ser1 == ser2 == ser3]
(* True *)
```

[image]

Comment: I have used your code for another f2x presented in below link, The output is not true anymore!  https://pastebin.com/RAPC8KpX

Comment: Your code doesn't work in this case :(

Comment: @HolgerMate It is `True` when I run it on a clean kernel.

Comment: I am completely confused :(. When I use quit kernel and then run the code I put in the above link, the out put is: some code==0. It doesn't returns True. Do you know why does it happens?

Comment: It returns: (a G H (G + H) (4 G^2 H^2 (G + H)^2 (G (2 Gd + Hd) + H (Gd + 2 Hd)) - 
      12 a G H (G + H) (G^3 (2 Gd + Hd) + G^2 H (3 Gd + Hd) + 
         H^3 (Gd + 2 Hd) + G H^2 (Gd + 3 Hd)) + 
      3 a^2 (3 G^5 (2 Gd + Hd) + 3 H^5 (Gd + 2 Hd) + 
         G^3 H^2 (12 Gd + 5 Hd) + G^4 H (15 Gd + 8 Hd) + 
         G^2 H^3 (5 Gd + 12 Hd) + G H^4 (8 Gd + 15 Hd))) Cos[
     th] (3 + Cos[2 tp]) (-1 + 
      3 Cos[2 (th + tp)]))/((-4 G^2 H^2 (G + H)^2 + 
      4 a G H (G + H) (G^2 + 3 G H + H^2) + 
      3 a^2 (G^4 - 2 G^3 H - 5 G^2 H^2 - 2 G H^3 + H^4)) r12 z) == 0

Comment: Maybe there is a problem in my version

Comment: Maybe there is a problem in my version of MM.

Comment: I am using MM 10.3. 'Maybe there is a problem in my version of MM:' Because I use quit kernel and then run the code. However the output is not true. I just guess that maybe my MM doesn't work well

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/79873/discussion-between-rhermans-and-holger-mate).