# Plotting the solutions to a system of differential equation

Tags: plotting, differential-equations

The problem is the following:

There is system of differential equations

```
V = -1; G = 0.1; x[t] = a*Exp[-Sqrt[-1]*p*t]; 
y[t] = b*Exp[-Sqrt[-1]*p*t]; p = -2 Cos[k];
s = ParametricNDSolveValue[{Sqrt[-1]*x'[t] == 
     V*x[t] - F*x[t]*Abs[x[t]]^2 - G*y[t], 
    Sqrt[-1]*y'[t] == V*y[t] - F*y[t]*Abs[y[t]]^2 - G*x[t], x[0] == 0, 
    y[0] == 1}, {x, y}, {t, 0, 15}, {F}];
```

The constraint on $a$ and $b$ is that $a^2+b^2=2$. Mathematica solves this without problem but then I want to get a plot for $F$ on x-axis vs $V-p$ on y-axis, which I am unable to plot. I tried with parametric plot but it gives errors. Any help will be greatly appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: Hi AtoZ and welcome! To make the most of Mma.SE start by **taking the [tour] now**. It will **help us to help you** if you write an [excellent question](https://goo.gl/BqKxV3). [Edit](https://goo.gl/ELLhTX) if improvable, show due diligence, give brief context, include **minimal working example** of code and data in **[formatted form](https://goo.gl/ELLhTX)**. As you receive **give back**, vote and answer questions, keep the site useful, be kind, correct mistakes and share what you have learned.

Comment: $V-p$ is a constant, what do you mean with plotting *vs* $V-p$?

Comment: essentially this is the energy $V$ is the local energy of an atom, for example. $p$ is coming from the stationary solutions in the form of x[t] = a*Exp[-Sqrt[-1]*p*t], This (stationary) ansatz will lead to a stationary equation and we have a factor $V-p$. I think I made a mistake I should leave $p$ then as a function of $k$? just like in the edited version of my question?

Comment: Is the problem for which you need help about plotting, writing the equation or about the physics?

Comment: No just the plotting.

Comment: If the problem is with plotting, then you should provide a **minimal working example** not your full physics problem. Does my answer solved your problem ? (even if you have changes the equations now.)

Comment: Yes great Thanks a lot for this help :-)

Comment: There are **[things to do after your question is answered](https://wolfr.am/v57DB3p4)**. But wait! It's a good idea to stay vigilant for some time, better approaches may come later improving over previous replies. Experienced users may point alternatives, caveats or limitations. New users should **test answers before [voting](https://wolfr.am/v57ItzJq)** and **wait 24 hours before [accepting](https://wolfr.am/v57LwTXD)** the best one. Participation is essential for the site, please do your part. And don't forget about the [tour].

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Code

is much more readable if indented, please in the future show as readable code. You save yourself [all sort of troubles](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/175670/10397) if you limit the scope of you definitions using [`Module`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Module.html).

```
psol = Module[
   {
    V = -1,
    G = 0.1,
    x, y, s, p
    },
   p = -2 Cos[k];
   s = ParametricNDSolveValue[
     {
      x'[t] == V*x[t] - F*x[t]*Abs[x[t]]^2 - G*y[t], 
      y'[t] == V*y[t] - F*y[t]*Abs[y[t]]^2 - G*x[t],
      x[0] == 0,
      y[0] == 1
      }
     , {x, y}
     , {t, 0, 15}
     , {F}
     ]
   ];
```

### [`Plot`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Plot.html)

```
Manipulate[
 Plot[
  Evaluate@Through[psol[F][t]]
  , {t, 0, 15}
  , PlotRange -> All
  ]
 , {{F, 0}, -0.99, 1}
 ]
```

[image]

### [`ParametricPlot`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/ParametricPlot.html)

```
Manipulate[
 ParametricPlot[
  Evaluate@Through[psol[F][t]]
  , {t, 0, 15}
  , AspectRatio -> 1
  , PlotRange -> {{-0.1, 0}, {0, 1}}
  , PlotTheme -> "Scientific"
  ]
 , {{F, 0}, -0.99, 1}
 ]
```

[image]