# Unexpected SetDelayed error while using a function with RGBColor

Tags: color, warning-messages

[image]

```
Clear[opa]
ListaCoresOPO18[opa_] := {
   RGBColor[31/255, 120/255, 180/255, opa],
   RGBColor[51/255, 160/255, 44/255, opa],
   RGBColor[227/255, 26/255, 28/255, opa],
   RGBColor[255/255, 127/255, 0/255, opa],
   RGBColor[106/255, 61/255, 154/255, opa],
   RGBColor[177/255, 89/255, 40/255, opa]
   };

ListaCoresOPO18[0.95]
```

Comment: @rhermans The = is the typical [line]=

Comment: OK the problem was lingering definitions. To prevent those please [read here](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/175910/10397).

Answer (score 3):

SOLVED:
The problem was that I should have use the name ListaCoresOPO18 before, SO....
after coding "Clear[ListaCoresOPO18];" in the first lines That was solved

[image]

Comment: Have a read here: [Different strategies to get a clean Kernel](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/175670/10397)