# ViewPoint messes up Export?

Tags: plotting, export, graphics3d

Version: 11.3.0 for Mac OS X x86 (64-bit) (March 7, 2018)

```
g = 
  Graphics3D[{}, 
    ImageSize -> {1920, Automatic}, 
    PlotRange -> {{-5, 5}, {-5, 5}, {-5, 5}}, 
    Background -> None, 
    Axes -> False, 
    AxesStyle -> Thick, 
    ViewPoint -> {0, -10, 5}];
g = Show[g, Graphics3D[Sphere[]]];
Magnify[g, .25]
Export["Sphere10.png", g];
```

The export is a blank image. If you remove the `ViewPoint`, the image comes out right. Is this a bug or am I doing something wrong?

### Edit

This problem keeps occurring for me at random times. Sometimes restarting Mathematica or my laptop fixes it but then the problem comes back. So it's the hardest kind of bug to find but it is extremely frustrating.

- [Here's a video that shows the behavior](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=IVAW_SRJC6Y&feature=youtu.be)

Comment: I copied your code and it works fine for me. Maybe you could try to `Rasterize` the image before exporting and that could solve the problem.

Comment: Export seems fine here on Windows (10.3) as well. Side note: you should be wary of using `g` for multiple consecutive definitions. This could mess up your result if the evaluation sequence is changed.

Comment: It works for me too: same configuration.

Comment: Given that it works for everybody else (I checked too) it suggest you have some lingering definitions or some extra code that we don't.  Read about getting a [clean kernel](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/175670/10397) particularly the part on [prevention](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/175910/10397) and on use of short variable names and limited scope. Somehow in like with the comment by YvesKlett, of your for multiple consecutive definitions.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because no one can reproduce the problem the user is experiencing.

Comment: I think this should remain open. This problem keeps occurring for me at random times. Sometimes restarting Mathematica or my laptop fixes it but then the problem comes back. So it's the hardest kind of bug to find but it is extremely frustrating. If someone wants to TeamViewer into my computer, they are welcome to.

Comment: @Wynne I reopened this even if others cannot reproduce it, but your video and further explanation (that I copied into the question) makes your post valid. I have several suggestions: First, you need to find out if the png export is broken (happened to me also recently). Try the following things: When you broke it, try `Rasterize` and see if you get a valid image. Try to export this *image* as png. Try to export graphics and image to a different format like `tif`. Change the background color of your graphics. If the export is still white then you can be more certain the png writer is damaged