# NumericQ or NumberQ don't work in nested numerical integrations (NIntegrate)

Tags: numerical-integration

I was trying to numerically perform the nested integration here below
$$
f(a)=\int_0^{a}\biggl(\int_x^{\infty}K_{\frac{1}{3}}(y)dy\biggr)dx,
$$
where $K_{\frac{1}{3}}(y)$ is a modified Bessel function of the second kind, and thus I thought that

```
BesselK13[var1_?NumericQ] := BesselK[1/3, var1]

a[x_?NumericQ] := NIntegrate[BesselK13[var2], {var2, x, \[Infinity]}]

b[y_?NumericQ] := NIntegrate[a[var3], {var3, 0, y}]
```

could do the trick, but the moment I ran

```
b[5]
```

I got the following stack trace

```
NIntegrate::inumr: The integrand BesselK[1/3,var1] has evaluated to non-numerical values for all sampling points in the region with boundaries {{\[Infinity],0. +var2}}.

NIntegrate::inumr: The integrand BesselK[1/3,var1] has evaluated to non-numerical values for all sampling points in the region with boundaries {{\[Infinity],0. +var2}}.

NIntegrate::inumr: The integrand BesselK[1/3,var1] has evaluated to non-numerical values for all sampling points in the region with boundaries {{\[Infinity],0. +var2}}.

General::stop: Further output of NIntegrate::inumr will be suppressed during this calculation.

1.04399
```

I also tried to replace `NumericQ` with `NumberQ` (in every possible permutation), but nothing changed. Do you happen to know what I'm doing wrong as well as a way to get rid of those annoying error messages? I mean, mathematica still returns the result (and that is great), but the fact that something seems off (and I can't understand the reasons behind it) really bothers me.
Thank you in advance for your time and kindness.

PS: I'm new to mathematica, so please be nice

Comment: On Window MMA version 12.3: b[5] yields 1.04399

Comment: If you  previously defined any of the functions without `?NumericQ`, Mathematic may be remembering the old definitions.  I suggest that you run your code in fresh notebook.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, why not use the double integration version of [`NIntegrate`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/NIntegrate):

```
NIntegrate[BesselK[1/3, v], {w, 0, 5}, {v, w, Infinity}]
```

> 1.04399

Second, you may have some old evaluations. What happens if you do:

```
Clear[BesselK13, a, b]
```

first?

Comment: Uh shut, it worked... By clearing all the function names everything works fine. However I don't really know how this could have happened: those were the only functions I defined and declared. Well, I guess I'll pay more attention from now on. Thank you so much!

Comment: Reading this may help to avoid this in the future  
 https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/175670/10397