# I need to create a series of polygons from a list of lists that form a stair step shape

Tags: graphics, polygons, iteration

This code

```
Graphics[{Red, Polygon[{{0, 0}, {0, 10}, {1, 10}, {1, 0}}]}];
Graphics[{Blue, Polygon[{{1, 0}, {1, 9}, {2, 9}, {2, 0}}]}];
Graphics[{Green, Polygon[{{2, 0}, {2, 8}, {3, 8}, {3, 0}}]}];
Show[%, %%, %%%]
```

nicely creates what I need:

[image]

But, I need ten of them and it is tedious to do it one line at a time. For the corners, I tried [`NestList`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/NestList.html) like this

```
NestList[{{# + 1, 0}, {# + 1, # - 1}, {# + 1, # - 1}, {# + 1, 
0}} &, {{0, 0}, {0, 10}, {1, 10}, {1, 0}}, 3]
```

but that did not work.

Should have hung in a moment longer. Found this to work

```
NestList[{{#[[1, 1]] + 1, 
0}, {#[[2, 1]] + 1, #[[2, 2]] - 1}, {#[[3, 1]] + 1, #[[3, 2]] - 
 1}, {#[[4, 1]] + 1, 0}} &, {{0, 0}, {0, 10}, {1, 10}, {1, 0}}, 3]
```

Still interested in better ways, though.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

While others offer more compact code, here I favour [strategies to keep a clean kernel](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/175910/10397), using scoping like [`Block`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Block.html) to avoid leaving lingering definitions and which also gives you a single place to edit the relevant parameters like `width`, `stepsize`, etc...

```
Block[
{
  width = 5,
  stepsize = 1,
  nBars = 10,
  initialheight = 40,
  height,
  xposition 
},
Graphics[
  Table[
  height=initialheight-stepsize*k;
  xposition = width*k;
  {
    Directive[EdgeForm[Thin],Hue[0.9*k/(nBars-1)]],
    Polygon[{
      {xposition,0},
      {xposition+width,0},
      {xposition+width,height},
      {xposition,height}
    }]
   }
   ,{k,0,nBars-1}]
  ]
]
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

```
step = Table[
   Graphics[{Red, 
     Polygon[{{x1, 0}, {x1, 10 - x1}, {x1 + 1, 10 - x1}, {x1 + 1, 
        0}}]}], {x1, 0, 10}];

Show@Table[step[[ii]], {ii, 1, 11}]
```

> [image: steps]

**Edit: to get different colors**

```
polygons = 
  Table[Polygon[{{x1, 0}, {x1, 10 - x1}, {x1 + 1, 10 - x1}, {x1 + 1, 
      0}}], {x1, 0, 10}];
colors = # & /@ RandomColor[11];
Graphics@(Thread@{colors, polygons})
```

> [image: 3]

Answer (score 1):

```
cols = ColorData[97][#] & /@ Range[10]
polys = Table[Rectangle[{i, 0}, {1 + i, 10 - i}], {i, 0, 9}]
Graphics[{
  Transpose[{cols, polys}]
  }]
```

[image]

The color list can be changed as required.