# What's the meaning of Global?

Tags: calculus-and-analysis, contexts

I'm calculating an integral,

`Integrate[(t e^(-z t) e^(-q t))/(1-e^(-t)), t]`,

and the result is

`` ConditionalExpression[Zeta[2, Global`z + Global`q], Re[Global`z + Global`q] > 0] ``.

I do not understand the meaning of `` Global`z `` and `` Global`q ``, and I'll appreciate your explanation.

Comment: Global is the global name space. This is where things that has no specific name space lives in. Basically when you define a variable, it goes by default to the global name space (called context in Mathematica). You can force variable to go into named context using the `Begin[contextName]`... command. btw, Did you mean `e` to be `Exp` ?  Start again from clean kernel. What do you get now?

Comment: `Clear[e,q,z]`.

Comment: Thanks @Nasser , yes, ```e``` denotes Euler's number, and that works. I tried again in a new notebook and the ```Global``` is gone.

Comment: In general lowercase characters don't have built-in meaning, what makes them good for your own variables. But even better, is to not have to use variables at all and keep a clean kernel. See about prevention [here](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/175670/10397). Also do not confuse the related but different constant `E` with the function `Exp`.