# Would it be poor advice to assign roman numerals as top variables?

Tags: variable, coding-style, indexed-variable

For example like so.

```
x = 10;
xi = 11;
xv = 15;
```

Is there an automated way to spit these numbers out maybe 1-1000.

Comment: So you've seen `RomanNumeral[]` already? Consider `Symbol[ToLowerCase[RomanNumeral[15]]]`...

Comment: @J.M. yes I saw that I just need access to the global variables or something like that.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

## I advise against

The reasons I will say it is "poor advice to assign roman numerals as top variables", is that it forces you to name the variable through strings operations, you end up with meaningless variable names (hard to debug) and in a functional programming language like *Mathematica*, you should be avoiding variables anyhow.

### String variables

In [this answer](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/94298/10397) Leonid Shifrin writes

> Using strings and subsequently `ToString` - `ToExpression` just to
> generate variable names is pretty much unacceptable, or at the very
> least should be the last thing you try. I don't know of a single case
> where this couldn't be replaced with a better solution. [...]
> The general [reason] is that they lead us outside of the symbolic world,
> and involve parsing, which is bad both for performance reasons and also just
> because one should avoid parsing as much as possible (for example, it may
> be unsafe).

### Meaningless variable names

The idea of using roman numerals for variables suggests there will be many variables following that pattern. If what you need is indexed variables, [there are other better solutions](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/94294/10397). Otherwise, these will be just meaningless variable names, which only hinder you and other people trying to understand the code.

### Lingering definitions

I think it would be better to exploit the functional style of Mathematica and avoid leaving lingering variable definitions. See [this question about keeping the kernel clean](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/175670/10397).

Answer (score 3):

`RomanNumeral` will produce roman numeral representation for a given integer as a string. So, you could do something like `Symbol[RomanNumeral[6]]` or `Symbol[ToLowerCase@RomanNumeral[6]]`. Whether this is a good idea depends on context. My initial knee jerk reaction is that, no, it's not a good idea, but there may be a context in which it makes sense.