# Exporting plot object gives errors

Tags: plotting, export

I am trying to save some plots. But the syntax below gives me Part, Set and FilterRules errors.

`teste4 := Return[Plot[ x, {x, 0, 10}]]; Export["/Users/tomasalvim/Desktop/teste.png", teste4]`

Does anyone know what the correct syntax should be to save the plot inside the Return[]?

Error: ""Part specification $Failed[[3,2]] is longer than depth of object""

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 3):

You don't need [`Return`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Return.html) . Also, no need for [`SetDelayed`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/SetDelayed.html) (`:=`) in this case.

```
Export[
    FileNameJoin[{$HomeDirectory,"test.png"}]
    , Plot[ x, {x, 0, 10}]
    , "PNG"
] // SystemOpen
```

Also, the error you quote doesn't come from that command. Try using a fresh kernel. [Read here for different strategies to get a clean Kernel.](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/175670/10397)

Comment: Thank you for the example, but I don't think it will do. I was trying to go for a minimal working example of the problem, the real function has 10+ arguments, and a Module[]. By the way I am exporting works SOME of the times. Other times I think it forces the kernel to quit, but I'm not sure that is the cause.

Comment: @TomásAlvim Well, your example does not show the problem. We can only answer yo what you show us.

Comment: You are right, in that the error does not come from that command. I'm not sure where it is coming from. I can't clear all the notebook because NDSolve takes too long to evaluate.

Comment: @TomásAlvim you can `DumpSave` the output of the slow calculation, restart the Kernel, and then `Get` the saved file again. Also, try  using `Echo[expr, "Label", Head]` or similar to debug intermediate steps. Somewhere you are getting a `$Failed`. Furthermore, use scoping and other techniques to avoid  [lingering definitions](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/175910/10397).

Comment: The DumpSave will save me loads of time, thanks.