# Understanding SetDelayed, ":="

Tags: function-construction, vector, assignment

Consider the example below,

```
p = {1, 2, 3};
x = {x1,x2,x3};
fun[x_] := {{1, 0, 0}, {0, 1, 1}} . (p + x);
fun2[x_] = {{1, 0, 0}, {0, 1, 1}} . (p + x);
```

I expected `fun[x]` and `fun2[x]` to give the same result, namely

```
{1 + x1, 5 + x2 + x3}
```

But `fun2[x]` yields

```
{{1+x1,1+x2,1+x3},{5+2 x1,5+2 x2,5+2 x3}}
```

Can you explain why `fun`'s output is a matrix?

Comment: Please add ```Clear["Global`*"];``` before the code and try again.

Comment: :O that fixed it, thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is not having a clean Kernel, you should see [this Q&A](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/175670/10397).

### Saving the question

Anyhow, trying to save the question in the title, to understand `SetDelayed`, you need to understand it in the context of the alternative `Set`.

#### From the documentation

##### [`Set`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Set.html)

> ```
> lhs=rhs
> ```
>
> evaluates `rhs` and assigns the result to be the value of `lhs`.
> From then on, `lhs` is replaced by `rhs` whenever it appears.

##### [`SetDelayed`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/SetDelayed.html)

> ```
> lhs:=rhs
> ```
>
> assigns `rhs` to be the delayed value of `lhs`. `rhs` is maintained
> in an unevaluated form. When `lhs` appears, it is replaced by `rhs`,
> evaluated afresh each time.

### Difference

The difference between `Set` and `SetDelayed` is when the definition is evaluated.

| [`SetDelayed`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/SetDelayed.html) | [`Set`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Set.html) |
| --- | --- |
| `f[x_]:= Echo[x^2]` | `g[x_] = Echo[x^2]` |
| [image] | [image] |

### Analysis

Notice that in the `SetDelayed` example [`Echo`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Echo.html) doesn't print at the moment of defining `f`, only when `f[2]` is evaluated.

On the contrary, in the `Set` example [`Echo`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Echo.html) prints at the moment of defining `g`, but not again when `g[2]` is evaluated.

Answer (score 1):

Consider what happens if you evaluate:

```
p = {1, 2, 3};
x = {x1,x2,x3};
fun2[x_] = {{1, 0, 0}, {0, 1, 1}} . (p + x);
```

This is evaluated at once. x is the function argument and therefore not replaced by {x1,x2,x3}.

(p+x) is evaluated to:

```
(p+x) -> ({1, 2, 3} + x)  -> {1+1,2+x,3+x}
```

And fun2 is defined as the result of:

```
 {{1, 0, 0}, {0, 1, 1}} .  {1+1,2+x,3+x} 

-> {{1 + x1, 1 + x2, 1 + x3}, {5 + 2 x1, 5 + 2 x2, 5 + 2 x3}}
```

Note, the argument x disappeared and fun2 will always return the same value independent of the argument.

On the other hand, "fun" is only evaluated when you call it as fun[x]. Then this is what happens:

```
fun[x] -> fun[{x1,x2,x3}] -> {{1, 0, 0}, {0, 1, 1}} . ({1, 2, 3}+{x1,x2,x3}) 

-> {{1, 0, 0}, {0, 1, 1}} .  {1 + x1, 2 + x2, 3 + x3} -> {1 + x1, 5 + x2 + x3}
```